# The weights of columns in the grid Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When i creating a table, i need columns of different sizes. But when I'm set different weights the columns does not resize. Please see the code below:

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root,                   # creating frame in root
              width=1440,
              height=900,
              bg="lightblue")
frame.grid(in_=root)                  # add frame in root row=0 column=0 (default)

canv1 = Canvas(frame,                 # creating canvas 
               bg="red",
               height=10)
canv2 = Canvas(frame,
               bg="green",
               height=20)
canv3 = Canvas(frame,
               bg="yellow",
               height=30)
canv4 = Canvas(frame,
               bg="blue",
               height=40)

canv1.grid(in_=frame, row=0, column=0) #add canvas in the grid
canv2.grid(in_=frame, row=0, column=1)
canv3.grid(in_=frame, row=0, column=2)
canv4.grid(in_=frame, row=0, column=3)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)     # set weights
frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=3)
frame.columnconfigure(3, weight=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `sticky` attribute when calling the `grid` function on the canvas widgets:

```
canv1.grid(in_=frame, row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

This will cause the edges of the canvas to stick to the sides of the space it was given. As the space grows and shrinks, so will the canvas.

By the way, you don't need the `in_` parameter since the canvas is a child of the frame.

Answer (score -1):

1. `columnconfigure` is used to share space when the window is resized
2. A widget size is determined by it's children sizes.

Therefore, if you want to modify the default' sizes, the best way is to modify the canvas' sizes:

```
canv1 = Canvas(frame,                 # creating canvas 
           bg="red",
           height=10,  
           width=700)
```

Comment: A widget's size _may_ be determined by its children, but that is not an absolute. It can also be affected by the geometry manager in use (pack, place, grid, or a containing canvas), or by its own dimensions. In this case the OP is already doing what you suggest, but that's only part of the solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley: in this case, the Frame size is determined by the canvas' sizes. And the OP has used the width attribute on the frame, not on the canvas.